# USB sound card (Just for headphone jack, not recording)

Tags: sound, usb

So I have found a few questions that asked about recording equipment that work with LINUX through USB,  but I don't need anything so extravagant (or expensive!), I just need something to be able to plug headphones in and listen to music at work.

The motherboard has no sound card, and I would love to just us a cheap USB one (some are as little as 4 dollars, but I am having trouble finding if they will work with ubuntu or not).

Do you guys have any suggestions of ones that will work?

I am sorry if this has been asked before, but everything I have found just talks about much more advanced equipment than I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most devices will work. (some better than others, but most do...) Ubuntu often uses generic drivers, so there even are devices that work without installing a driver under Ubuntu, while, using Windows, you have to download a driver specially written for this device.

The only way to find out is to buy one ($4 isn't that much...) and try it. Or if you got the model name of a specific one, google it together with *ubuntu* and you may find something. If it's not working, try to get informations about that specific device used with Ubuntu, or try to return or resell it...